# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'providers')

Tags: typescript, ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

[image]

here i am getting importing web3 version 1.2.11 as

`import Web3 from 'web3'`

`const readonlyProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL)` in typescript.

after compiling getting in javascript

`const readonlyProvider = new web3_1.default.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL);`

where web3_1.default is undefine in console.

Answer (score 0):

in early versions of web3, there was no `Web3.providers.` we used to create a provider and then plug it into `new Web3` like this

```
let web3;
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3 !== "undefined") {
  window.ethereum.enable();
  // we are on browser and we are running metamask
  // window.web3 is old spec. recent one is window.ethereum
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3);
  // web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)
} else {
  // we are on server or user is not runnint metamask
  const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: {
      phrase: process.env.METAMASK_KEY,
    },
    providerOrUrl: process.env.YOUR_PRIVATE_NODE, // GOERLI MAYBE
  });

  // THIS IS HOW WE USED TO INITIALIZE WEB3 INSTANCE
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the ES6 import syntax to import the `web3` module. However, when the typescript code is compiled to javascript, the compiled code is using a different syntax to import the `web3` module, which is causing the `web3_1.default` is `undefined` error in the console.

If so, here's how i would recommend:

1. Use `require` syntax instead of `import`.

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const readonlyProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL);
```

2. Enable `esModuleInterop` in your typescript configuration. The `esModuleInterop` option in the typescript configuration file (tsconfig.json) changes how typescript handles module imports. When `esModuleInterop` is set to **true**, typescript will use a different syntax to import modules, which might solve your issue.

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "esModuleInterop": true
 }
}
```

3. Use the `import * as` syntax. This syntax tells typescript to import all exports from the `web3` module as properties of an object.

```
import * as Web3 from 'web3';
const readonlyProvider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerURL);
```

If you found that this might not the solution or useless answer, please do inform me so I will remove it.

Comment: Solved that error thank you